# Why I can't reproduce Keras results?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, deep-learning

I know that there is a problem with reproducibility in keras. However due to my research I created a function:

```
def set_seed():
    seed_value = 42
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
    session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
    np.random.seed(seed_value)
    random.seed(seed_value)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
    K.set_session(sess)
```

which should assure me a reproductive results in keras.

**My problem**

I'm trying to run self-created grid search on neural network using keras:

```
# Early stopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience = 50)
callbacks=[es]

# Possible learning rates
learning_rates = np.linspace(0.1, 10**(-5), 10)

# Run grid search on one layer
set_seed()
mse1 = np.array([])
rate1 = np.array([])
neuron_number1 = np.array([])
for rate in learning_rates[0:2]:
    for neuron in range(1, 3):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(neuron, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))
        model.summary()
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=SGD(lr=rate),  metrics=['mse'])
        history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=50, validation_split=0.5, callbacks=[es])
        mse1 = np.append(mse1, history.history['val_loss'][-1])
        rate1 = np.append(rate1, rate)
        neuron_number1= np.append(neuron_number1, neuron)
        

neural_summary1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = [neuron_number1, rate1, mse1]) 
neural_summary1 = neural_summary1.transpose()
neural_summary1.columns = ["number_of_neurons", "learning_rate", "mse"]


print(neural_summary1.iloc[neural_summary1['mse'].idxmin()])
number_of_neurons    2.000000
learning_rate        0.088890
mse                  0.159922
```

But when I run it apart from grid search:

```
set_seed()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.088890),  metrics=['mse'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=50, validation_split=0.5, callbacks=[es])
print(history.history['val_loss'][-1])
8.767917346954345
```

which is different than result obtained previously from grid search.

Do you know where is mistake in my code or why is not working?

Packages that I use are the following:

```
import pandas
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import os
from keras import backend as K
```

Comment: "Why does my hyperparameter search find value X" is a way too open and general question for SO.

Comment: My question is not why does my hyperparameter search find value X, but why I obtained different results from grid search and not from grid search whereas both are on the same seed

Comment: I obtained mse equal to 0.159922 from grid search and building exactly same neural network I obtained mse equal to 8.767917346954345

Comment: Setting the hash seed environment variable within the program will likely have no effect. You would need to set it on the command line.

Comment: What do you mean by set in on the command line?

Comment: `env PYTHONHASHSEED=123 python script.py` (on Unix-like machines).

Comment: in your loop, u need to call set_seed() every time before model = Sequential()

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I already tried this solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't give wanted result.

Comment: @Lucian could you please prove this